# css scoped tag styling has side effect on outer scope in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

I don't understand why scoped tag styling, which is like this

```
.parent > input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

has side effect to the `input` tag that is not nested in the `parent` tag.

demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/scoped-styling-question-ecs7o?file=/src/styles.module.css:377-430

I think the second input tag should have outline default style since it is not nested in parent tag.

I used `npx create-react-app` to set up this project.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your css is nested inside `.parent` only for iframe. If you want to nest everything inside `.parent`, you should transform

```
.parent > iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
... {
    ...
}
```

in

```
.parent > iframe,
.parent > h1,
.parent > h2,
.parent > h3,
... {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In addition, I'm not a react-dev, but your `className={styles.parent}` seems a bit weird to me as `style` is a css file

Comment: Wow Thank you so much !. In terms of your question, you might want to look at css module docs https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules